# Does the Tate pairing agree with the Brauer-Manin pairing

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be a proper, smooth, geometrically integral variety over a field $k$. Let $A$ be (the identity component of) its Picard variety and let $B$ be (the identity component) of its Albanese variety. One has the Tate pairing
$$
\langle\,,\,\rangle_1 : H^1(k,A) \times B(k) \to \operatorname{Br}(k)\,,
$$
and the Brauer-Manin pairing,
$$
\langle\,,\,\rangle_2 : \operatorname{Br}(X) \times \operatorname{CH}_0(X) \to \operatorname{Br}(k),
$$
where $\operatorname{CH}_0(X)$ is the group of zero-cycles modulo rational equivalence.

There are obvious maps
$$
\operatorname{CH}_0(X) \leftarrow A_0(X) \rightarrow B(k)\,,
$$
where $A_0(X)$ is the kernel of the degree map on $\operatorname{CH}_0(X)$. There are also maps
$$
\operatorname{Br}_1(X) \to H^1(k,\operatorname{Pic}(\overline{X})) \leftarrow H^1(k,A)\,,
$$
the first coming from the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence and the second induced by the inclusion $\operatorname{Pic}^0(\overline{X}) \subset \operatorname{Pic}(\overline{X})$. (Here $\operatorname{Br}_1(X)\subset\operatorname{Br}(X)$ is the algebraic Brauer group.)

**Question:** Are the pairings above compatible with these maps. Specifically, given $z \in A_0(X)$, $F \in \operatorname{Br}_1(X)$ and $T \in H^1(k,A)$ such that $F$ and $T$ have the same image in $H^1(k,\operatorname{Pic}(\overline{X}))$, do we have
$$
\langle T,z'\rangle_1 = \langle F,z''\rangle_2\,,
$$
where $z'$ and $z''$ are the images of $z$?

**Remark:** When $X$ is a curve, the answer is yes, as shown in *Stephen Lichtenbaum*, [**Duality theorems for curves over $p$-adic fields**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=242831), *Invent. Math.* **7** (1969), 120--136..

Comment: This looks rather similar to Proposition 3.4 in http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02026.